# Does anyone know what the function 'Parse_vars' in python does?

Tags: python, parsing, initialization, pyramid

I am fairly new to python and particularly the pyramid framework - I am trying to initialize the database and  am getting this parse_vars is not defined error. Does anyone know what the function parse_vars does? I can't find information anywhere on the internet about it?

Maybe if i understand what its doing I can solve the error,

Here is the code

```
def main(argv=sys.argv):
    if len(argv) < 2:
        usage(argv)
    config_uri = argv[1]
    options = parse_vars(argv[2:])
    setup_logging(config_uri)
    settings = get_appsettings(config_uri, options=options)

    engine = get_engine(settings)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    session_factory = get_session_factory(engine)

    with transaction.manager:
        dbsession = get_tm_session(session_factory, transaction.manager)

        editor = User(name='editor', role='editor')
        editor.set_password('editor')
        dbsession.add(editor)

        basic = User(name='basic', role='basic')
        basic.set_password('basic')
        dbsession.add(basic)

        FTIRModel = FTIRModel(
            name='FrontPage',
            creator=editor,
            data='This is the front page',
        )
        dbsession.add(FTIRModel)
```

and here is the error

[image: image of a stacktrace instead of the stacktrace, something that is terribly annoying and useless to everyone, but the person asking the question]

Comment: Never post images of text. Always post the actual stacktrace or error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code for the function [`parse_vars`](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/pyramid/scripts/common.py#L3-L16):

```
def parse_vars(args):
    """
    Given variables like ``['a=b', 'c=d']`` turns it into ``{'a':
    'b', 'c': 'd'}``
    """
    result = {}
    for arg in args:
        if '=' not in arg:
            raise ValueError(
                'Variable assignment %r invalid (no "=")'
                % arg)
        name, value = arg.split('=', 1)
        result[name] = value
    return result
```

As its docstring describes, it converts the values from a configuration file (`development.ini` for example) into a Python dict.

It looks like you copied code from this step in the [SQLAlchemy + URL dispatch wiki tutorial](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/wiki2/definingmodels.html#edit-scripts-initializedb-py), then left out critical pieces that will cause the script to fail, most critically:

```
from pyramid.scripts.common import parse_vars
```

Comment: Thank you - this answered my question. I did exactly that :D

Comment: @SarachGriffin Please accept my answer. This lets others know it solved your issue with a friendly green check mark.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a standard function, so it is hard to tell what it is expected to do.  The most common implementation seems to be part of the [Pyramid framework](https://trypyramid.com/), and you could import it with:

```
from pyramid.scripts.common import parse_vars
```

But it is hard to tell whether it will do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing allows the values of Parameters and Variables to be used in various areas of JAMS such as a Job's source or in an Alert. This can be very useful for making your Jobs and other JAMS objects more dynamic. The syntax described below shows examples when  using Parsing.

To access the value of a Variable or Parameter use the format "<>" or "<>". Parsing allows you to assign the values of Variables or Parameters to a variable within your source, or by directly using the values themselves. It is possible to use parsing to call Variables from other Folders.